# What is the difference between a software developer, software programmer and software engineer?

Tags: job-search, title, job-description

I've been working in the IT sector as an "associate software developer" for the past two years. While applying for new jobs, I've seen job titles like "software developer", "software programmer" and "software engineer", but the the requirements often seem to be almost identical. Is there any difference between the roles associated with these job titles?

Comment: In my experience, the terms mean the same thing and are used interchangeably.

Comment: Sometimes a Programmer has a little bit lower salary than a Developer/Engineer, but it's probably more to do with the company than any common practice. Perhaps to do with less responsibilies, or that the job is more purely coding - no client meetings, requirements gathering, or such - while a developer/engineer might do those activities in addition to coding.

Comment: Besides the legal implications, it usually gives away how the company sees people. By extension it is something you could use to get a sense of what the company culture is. Of course this is just an indicator among many others.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about terminology. The distinction between these terms is subjective and arbitrary.

Comment: also, see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/4951

Comment: Take a look at this answers: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/27299/14671

Answer (score 32):

It is possible that a particular company may use those titles to mean different things and to describe different positions within that company.

But I do not believe that there is a clear distinction between them which is common across different companies.

Personally I have had all three of "developer", "programmer" and "engineer" as titles in different jobs involving the programming of software. There was no relationship between the differing titles and the differing work I did at those jobs.

Don't stress the titles too much, just look at the actual requirements and the actual job descriptions.

**Edit:** as has been pointed out in the comments, the title "Engineer" carries significance in some countries, e.g. Finland (thanks Juha) and Canada (thanks Dogbert). It's not the case where I am (Australia) nor does it appear to be the case in the USA or the UK, where there may be an *implication* of greater education or expertise, but I think no more than an implication.

Comment: Engineer usually refers to a legal title that requires some sort of exam after taking a degree (at least in some countries), so, legally, a software engineer is a software developer but the opposite need not be true. No idea whether the US have such a distinction, or whether it is taken into consideration.

Comment: @Bakuriu In the UK I don't believe you have to have any kind of qualification for label yourself as an engineer. It's a bone of contention for those of us who did engineering degrees...

Comment: In Finland, an Engineering diploma specifically states (translated) "With receiving this diploma, you have the **right** to use the title of ______ Engineer". Emphasis mine.

Comment: In USA, my position was once "Systems Programmer" while what I was doing was web application developer. Titles have little meaning, unless single company uses more than one. Then, you have a good question to ask at the interview: "In your company, what is difference between X and Y?"

Comment: @JuhaUntinen: What's put in place of the _______? Something like the academic degree?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: "Electrical", "IT", "Mechanical", "Chemical" and so on, depending on your degree programme.

Comment: While in the US "Engineer" tends to imply a more formal educational background, the only time there is an actual written requirement for it is if you are a "Certified Professional Engineer," which implies you have passed an exam like the one mentioned by @Bakuriu

Comment: @Liath Yes, I believe British Gas send engineers to check your boiler, and if they struggle they call in a technician (obviously a more prestigious title). I hear when you have a PhD in Engineering this title use only compounds the misery of said broken boiler. I would like to add my meaningless (but still quite nice) title of "software consultant" into the fray.

Comment: Although the distinction may have become blurry over time, when I went to college, I studied "Software Engineering" which meant that one had to take classes in formal software structuring, complex software systems (operating systems, etc) and take labs involving developing software in teams and using modules from other teams. To be a Software Engineer, you had to have the degree. To be a "programmer" could just mean you taught yourself how to write Excel VB scripts, or it could mean more than that. It's a more general term but narrower in scope as far as required credentials.

Comment: It's illegal to use "engineer" in your job title or "engineering" in your company name in Canada unless your most senior engineer or those signing off on the product are registered Professional Engineers (P.Eng.). https://apeg.bc.ca/For-Members/Professional-Practice/Professional-Practice-FAQ

Comment: @Dogbert cheers, have edited to mention Canada alongside Finland as a country where "engineer" has real meaning

Answer (score 5):

In theory, development would be the whole process from taking the requirements over planning the project to its execution, while engineering is planning the technical design of the software and programming is the execution of these designs.

But in practice, there is little difference between these titles. In the real world, a person having either of these job titles might be expected to cover the whole scope of a software developement or be reduced to being only a code monkey.  The "Senior Software Developer" in company A might have even less responsibility than the "Junior Programmer" in company B.

To learn what kind of work a position actually entails, read between the lines of the actual job description and which skills it states as required. Or even better: ask them.

Comment: +1: I agree. In fact, the term "software programmer" as applied to these roles is more often than not nothing more than evidence that upper management has _no idea_ what software development actually entails.